# WPF Data Grid:- Iterate through Each row or record (C# 4.0)

Tags: .net, wpf, wpfdatagrid

Suppose I have **select one row** in `Data Grid` provided by **VS2010.**

Now suppose I need **only records below the selected row** then what should I have to do?

i think this could be done through **iterating over each row of** `Data Grid`.But how?

**Why this? Because**

Suppose I have bound one collection to datagrid.

And now I **reorder** the `Data Grid` using the **header of columns** of `Data Grid`.

Then records in `Data Grid`are **reordered** but the records in underling collection **remains unordered.**

Means **re-ordering** does **not affect under lying collection**.

So **I can’t use it** for getting the records **below the selected row.**

**NOTE:** here reordering is necessary

Thanks…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the [`CollectionView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionview.aspx) which wraps the original collection and in which the ordering happens by using [`CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource.getdefaultview.aspx).

Your DataGrid needs to sync with the current item, then you get the position and get the object following that, e.g.:

```
<DataGrid IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" />
```

```cs
var view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Data) as ListCollectionView;
if (view != null)
{
    var i = view.CurrentPosition;
    var nextEmp = view.GetItemAt(i + 1) as Employee;
    if (nextEmp != null)
    {
        nextEmp.Name = "Steve!";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much this is exact answer.  But is there not any LINQ query which will when fire on "view" gives all the records from currently selected to last record of "view".  Thanks..

Comment: I am not sure if LINQ works well with this since you have to retrieve objects via that method and it is probably also how you find out if you reached the end, `while` blocks may be preferrable here.

Comment: ya i currently going with ,`while` block...till not finding good solution....thank you so much for your valuable reply..